# защита файла на сервере

Tags: .htaccess, apache

есть в папке public_html файл с именем admin.php
нужно защитить его логин:пароль

писал так .HTACCESS :

```
<FilesMatch "admin.php">
AuthName "Member Only"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/logincpanel/.htpasswd
require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

для .htpasswd
user:passs

Загрузил на сервер два этих файла в public_html и

получил Internal Server Error

Прочитал коментарий: "После переноса файлов в целевую директорию надо отредактировать путь к файлу  .htpasswd в .htaccess . Если из примера, то надо добавить secret-files в путь. Чтобы было: **/**/secret-files /.htpasswd Иначе словите Internal Server Error"

не совсем понял что надо сделать?

Comment: secret-files / добавил . всё равно 500

Answer (score 0):

Содержимое файла `.htaccess` для вашей задачи корректное.

Ошибка 500 указывает на то, что в настройках apache-сервера для вашего сайта не указана деректива `AlowOverride` c опцией `AuthConfig` - посмотрите в error-логи сайта.

У вас у настройка сайта должно быть примерно так:

```
<Directory "/path/to/site/public_html">
    ...
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    ...
</Directory>
```